# Creating Universal app for itunes?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store-connect, ios-universal-app

I know it is not a technical question but i can't find it else where. My iPhone app is on itunes but itunes shows different tabs for iPhone and iPad apps, and my app is showing in iPhone app category.But i want to show it in both iPhone and iPad.For this i'v to change my app to Universal.

**Now my question** is that, if i update my app to universal without any change in code or even without separate storyboard for ipad, will apple accept it?If yes, will it be shown on both iPhone and iPad apps categories?

Comment: You can update your application with version....apple accept it you need to change your app version only ....

Comment: so i can submit my app to app store with just change my app from iPhone only to Universal with new version?

Comment: Yes Change only deployment info in your project Device_ make it Universal and upload it on app store .....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*if i update my app to universal without any change in code or even without separate storyboard for ipad, will apple accept it* - **YES**

Make sure your views are properly displaying in both iPhone and ipad if you are not going to change code or storyboard. Otherwise, may be apple will reject. *Also you need to update your build version accordingly*.

Comment: You can update your application with version....apple accept it you need to change your app version only ....

Comment: so i can submit my app to app store with just change my app from iPhone only to Universal with new version?